# Nested IF statements returning 'FALSE' on time check

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to write a formula to show the below:

General rule:
If actual (C2) or forecast (B2) time is less than start time (A2) + 15mins then return status (D2) "on track", if its more than or equal to start time + 15mins then return status "late"

What I am trying to also include is a rule to check if actual time is 'blank' then use the rule against forecast time but if actual time is filled then over-ride the forecast time formula and check against actual time instead. I've written the below formula but is returning 'FALSE' when i have filled in actual time. Please help!

```
=IF(C2="",
    IF(B2<A2+TIME(0,15,0),"On track",
        IF(B2>=A2+TIME(0,15,0),"Late",
        IF(C2<A2+TIME(0,15,0),"On track","Late"))))
```

Comment: It's a paren nesting issue. Still analyzing, but you might be better off using `IFS` than `IF` as well

Comment: `=IF(C2="",
    IF(B2<A2+TIME(0,15,0),"On track",
        IF(B2>=A2+TIME(0,15,0),"Late")),
        IF(C2<A2+TIME(0,15,0),"On track","Late"))`

Comment: Another thing I'd recommend is using `ISBLANK` rather than checking equality.

Comment: @JakobLovern I prefer the `=""`. 1.  It is less typing. 2. If the `""` is returned by a formula `ISBLANK` will return `FALSE`